# Is there a difference between "exactly the same page" and "the exact same page"?

Tags: difference

1. We were both looking in the same book but each at **exactly the** same page.
2. We were both looking in the same book but each at **the exact** same page.

Is there any difference (whatever difference) between the former and the latter sentence?

Comment: A semantic difference?

Comment: I'm having a real hard time trying to pinpoint the difference... One thing that is obvious is that one is an adverb and the other is an adjective.

Comment: In the first statement "Exactly",  an adverb, is showing the speciality of the action "looking at". In the second statement, "Exact" is functioning as an adjective, showing the importance of  "the same page". Here, it is bolstering the fact that the two books are on the same page. Thus, the two sentences have the same meaning; the only difference is that the stress is at two different facts in the two sentences.

Comment: I thought so too, at first, however, this seems to be an incorrect point of view. I guess that this is because eventually both "exactly" and "exact" speak of the "same page".

Comment: We were both looking at exactly the same page from the same book. We were both looking at the exact same page from the same book. **Exact same** is being used as an adverb to mean very, though technically it isn't, an adverb to qualify the adjective same.

Comment: @Lambie I think "very" acts as an adjective when it is used just before a "noun". See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/very. So, as per your definition "Exact same" is working as an adjective.

Comment: Yes, I agree that "exact" is also functioning as an adverb for the adjective "same". So, "exact" and "exactly" both are adverbs here, former is applied on "same", the latter on "looking at".  "Exactly" is pointing at the verb, that's why the determiner "the" is used after "exactly" in the first sentence. If "exactly" were pointing to "same", then it must have come after "the".

Comment: Can we say that the word "same page" is acting as a noun phrase? If it is considered as a phrase, then "exact" would qualify as an adjective.

Comment: exact same=very same, exact works as an adverb here even though it is not an adverb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real difference in meaning - both words have the same derivation. Lots of adjectives have corresponding adverbs.

- Exact / Exactly
- Precise / Precisely
- Correct / correctly

How you use them can differ. For example, an adverb can often be placed before or after the verb it affects:

> - They were born on precisely the same day.
> - They were born on the same day precisely.

The key point here is not to over-analyse this particular example, because, while '*the exact same*' is certainly an idiom said by many English speakers, it doesn't hold up to grammatical scrutiny because it is a *redundancy*. If two things are "the same" (and not just 'similar') then they have no differences. They cannot be any *more* 'the same'. "The exact same" is just something said for emphasis rather than meaning.

Comment: In your example the structuring doesn't consort with the structuring in the example I provided.

Comment: @SovereignSun You're right, but the principle is the same. I'm teaching you to fish, not giving you a fish.